Add days to date without using adddate
Add a integer number of days to a date in MySQL without using adddate.
Obviously the following code does the job:
adddate('2024-01-01',100)

My failure attempt is:
'2024-01-01' + 100

Does anyone know an alternative way of adding days to date in MySQL?

mysql> select '2024-01-01' + interval 100 day as date;
+------------+
| date       |
+------------+
| 2024-04-10 |
+------------+

Read more about this type of expression here: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/expressions.html#temporal-intervals
